# How to download the csv file using Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

I need to download the CSV files from this page but i am not able to do so. PFA the screenshot of the page from where the files has to be downloaded :

[image]

[image]

I have tried the below code but it doesn't work

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) wd;          

js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();",wd.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ctrl2016284712']/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[24]/td[7]/a")));
```

Comment: the screenshot is very nice, however a HTML snippet would be much more useful.

Comment: Hi Dan, Thanks for the prompt response. I have uploaded the scrennshot of HTML snippet.

Comment: By.xpath("//*[@id='ctrl2016284712']/, this id must be dynamic in nature thats why your are unable to click, one way to know weather it is dynamic load twice and  check id value

Comment: Yes it is dynamic in nature. So how should i go ahead ?

Comment: @Novice go with creating dynamic Xpath with contains

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you could get the 'href' attribute from the anchor tag and just append your base url to it. Then do driver.get(baseURL + href). Also if you face any difficulty creating an xpath then do let me know, I will explain it more in detail.

**Updated answer:**
Try this xpath since you want to download only csv type of file: `//table[@class='lcb']/tbody/tr/td/table[@class='ibody']/tbody/tr/td[contains(translate(text(), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'),'csv')]/parent::tr/td[7]`

Comment: wd.get("https://www.shipper-ml.com/viewReports.do?ctrl=reportListForDownload&action=DownloadReport&param=23");  

I gave this but no success. I am getting "HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error" error.

Comment: Can you help me ? It would be very great. I am stuck on this from a long time.

Comment: Is it possible to share the url on PM? I could have a look

Comment: Yes. Can you give me your mail id ?

Comment: Try this xpath: `//table[@class='ibody']/tbody/tr[24]/td[7]/a` . Let me know if that works

Comment: Did you try it, any luck?

Comment: Yes I tried. But no success

Comment: my email ID: gudinholee[at]gmail[dot]com, send over the link and creds, I'll get the xpath for you. There is no element on earth that cannot be located :P

Comment: I have sent.. please check

Comment: Now try this: //table[@class='lcb']/tbody/tr/td/table[@class='ibody']/tbody/tr[2]/td[7]

Answer (score 0):

I would not go from the structure in your case but rather from a content. Here is the example of html:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <table class="table table-condensed">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                   <th>h1</th>
                   <th>h2</th>
                   <th>h3</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>28112706.CSV</td>
                    <td>12</td>
                    <td>28/11/2018 09:13</td>
                    <td>
                        <a hef="asdfsdf">
                            <img/>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

and here is the example of xpath:

```
//tbody/tr[./td[text()='28112706.CSV']|./td[text()='28/11/2018 09:13']]/td/a
```

that returns `a` element that resides in the table row where we have the cell with `28112706.CSV` **AND** the cell with `28112706.CSV`

So your challenge is to define the row you want to use and describe the conditionss for the content in xPath expression.

Comment: Hi Alexey, it's a third party website so I cannot make changes in that.
And also the id's are generated dynamically so how to handle that ?

Comment: @Novice did I mention any changes to the website? I just described how you should build your xpath to define the row you d like to operate with to download file. You should refer to the content, not to the structure.

Comment: I am not sure how to do it. Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking at downloading *all* the CSV files, you may want to use `findElements()` to get all the links and click each one. Looking at the image and HTML snippet, looks like you have a single link in each row pointing to the CSV file.

```
List<WebElement> allLinks = wd.findElements(By.cssSelector("tr a"));
```

Should return all the links. Now you can loop through the list and click on each element. Something like:

```
for(WebElement e: allLinks)
   e.click()
```

Comment: Hi Dakshinamurthy, Actually I am not able to point to table because as per my understanding first I should be able to point to table and then only I should go for downloading the files. Isn't it ?

wd.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ctrl1857714716']/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table"));

I tried this but no success.

Comment: You do not need to descend from the table onwards. The above selector should give you all links in each of the row.

Comment: Couple of points. 1. Prefer CSS selectors to XPath. 2. Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Selectors for a quick introduction to CSS selectors.